# How do we know that these orthogonal projections coincide?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, time-series

Let $\left\{X_t\right\}$ be a zero mean stationary process.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and consider the Hilbert space $L^2=L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. It has the inner product $\langle X,Y\rangle=E(XY)$. Moreover, consider $K_1=\overline{sp}\left\{X_2,\ldots,X_n\right\}$, $K_2=\overline{sp}\left\{X_1-P_{K_1}X_1\right\}$ and $K_n=\overline{sp}\left\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\right\}$. $K_1$ and $K_2$ are orthogonal subspaces of $K_n$.

For $Y\in L^2$, let $P_{K_1}Y$, $P_{K_2}Y$ and $P_{K_n}Y$ denote the orthogonal projection mappings of $L^2$ onto the subspaces $K_1, K_2, K_n$.

> > Show that for any $Y\in L^2$, we have
> >     $$
> > P_{K_n}Y=P_{K_1}Y+P_{K_2}Y.
> > $$

---

My first idea was to write down the expressions of the projections as linear combinations.

Since $P_{K_n}Y\in K_n$, we can write it as some linear combination, i.e.
$$
P_{K_n}Y=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i.
$$
By the projection theorem, this is unique.

On the other hand, we have that $P_{K_1}X_1=\sum_{i=2}^nd_iX_i$ so that
$$
P_{K_1}Y+P_{K_2}Y=\sum_{i=2}^n b_iX_i+c\cdot (X_1-P_{K_1}X_1)\\
=\sum_{i=2}^n b_iX_i+cX_1-\sum_{i=2}^n cd_iX_i\\
=\sum_{i=2}^n (b_i-cd_i)X_i + cX_1.
$$

This is a linear combination of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, too.

How do I know now, that both expression do coincide? Do not see that.

Comment: @Crostul Do not understand your comment. Since we are considering the Hilbert space $L^2$ and subspaces of it, it has of course something to do with $L^2$. Surely, this is no special case for $L^2$; for any other Hilbert space, my question would be the same: How to show the desired identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is a closed subspace of $L^{2}$, then $m$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ iff $m \in M$ and $(x-m)\perp M$. That's the definition I'll use.

You have subspaces $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_n$ such that
$$
                           K_n=K_1\oplus K_2,\\
                           L^{2}=K_{n}^{\perp}\oplus K_1\oplus K_2
$$
where the sums on the right are direct and orthogonal. You want to show that
$$
                        P_{K_n}=P_{K_1}+P_{K_2}.
$$
If $x \in L^2$, then $x=k_n^{\perp}+k_1+k_2$. Then $P_{K_1}x=k_1$ because $k_1 \in K_1$ and $(x-k_1)=k_n^{\perp}+k_2$ is orthogonal to $K_1$. So,
$$
                       P_{K_1}x=k_1,\;\;P_{K_2}x=k_2, \\
                \implies P_{K_n}x=k_1+k_2=P_{K_1}x+P_{K_2}x.
$$

Comment: How do you know that $K_n$ and $L^2$ can be decomposed like this?

Comment: @M.Meyer : Gram-Schmidt procedure is one way because $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_n$ are finite-dimensional.